# Xaml proprety of workflow definition

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

```
WorkflowDefinition _WorkflowDefinition = new WorkflowDefinition(clientContext);
_WorkflowDefinition .Xaml =  ?
```

What the `Xaml` proprety of and `WorkflowDefinition` must get  as value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow definitions can also be serialized to XAML. These serialized definitions can be reloaded for editing or inspection, passed to a build system for compilation, or loaded and invoked.

To create a workflow definition for serialization, the `ActivityBuilder` class is used. Creating an `ActivityBuilder` is very similar to creating a `DynamicActivity`. Any desired arguments are specified, and the activities that constitute the behavior are configured.

Sample XAML

```
<Activity 
  x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" 
  x:Class="Add" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="Operand1" Type="InArgument(x:Int32)" />
    <x:Property Name="Operand2" Type="InArgument(x:Int32)" />
  </x:Members>
  <Sequence>
    <WriteLine Text="[Operand1.ToString() + &quot; + &quot; + Operand2.ToString()]" />
    <Assign x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Value="[Operand1 + Operand2]">
      <Assign.To>
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
          <ArgumentReference x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" ArgumentName="Result" />
          </OutArgument>
      </Assign.To>
    </Assign>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

For more read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458319(v=vs.110).aspx